# Logging in anonymous user with custom token removes the anonymous status

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

What is the exact definition of an anonymous user in firebase authentication?

when I call `signInAnonymously()` obviously the user is `isAnonymous: true`.
But if I create a custom token for the user via the admin sdk and then log in again with that customToken (using `signInWithCustomToken(token)`) the user is no longer `isAnonymous`.

Is this a bug or intended? And is there any workaround to persist that anonymous state?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the exact definition of an anonymous user in firebase authentication?

It's a user account that doesn't have a person's identity attached to it.  It merely recognizes that someone (probably the same person) is using the app over time, on a specific device.

> But if I create a custom token for the user via the admin sdk and then log in again with that customToken (using signInWithCustomToken(token)) the user is no longer isAnonymous.

When you sign in a new account, the prior account is always immediately signed out.  This is true for all types accounts, and has nothing to do with anonymous auth.  There can only be one user signed in at a time.

> Is this a bug or intended?

Working as intended.

> And is there any workaround to persist that anonymous state?

No, the anonymous account is signed out after you sign in a new account.  If you instead want to *upgrade* that anonymous account with a known identity, you should look into linking a new identity to the existing anonymous account by [converting the anonymous account to a permanent account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account).  This will preserve the account, but it will no longer be anonymous (as it now contains some identity information in it).

Comment: The problem is that I need to create a customToken for the anonymous user and then sign in that anonymous user with the created token at a different auth app.
I need to have the information that the user is anonymous here.

Comment: Then check that the currentUser is an anonymous auth account, and take action accordingly.  If you're having a specific problem with that, I suggest posting a new question describing that problem, and the code you have for that so far.